# VS Code don't focus message input on source control

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i click source control or use the shortcut for source control it focuses the Message input on default.
How can i disable this or have shortcut focus on the list and not on the input

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour with either the `View: Show Source Control` or `Source Contro: Focus on Source Control View` commands. It always focuses the listing for me. What keyboard shortcut are you using, and what command ID is it bound to?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Comment: I have this when i have no files open but do have changes. Then the cursor is focused on the input. But i want it on the list to navigate